# Redux thunk returning a promise instead of a resolved value

Tags: javascript, redux, web3js

I am trying to return a web3 value rather than a promise in order for me to call the getId method.

my return value for web3 hasn't been resolved thus is still a promise hence Im unable to call getId method on it

Can any experienced redux user point out to me what is wrong with my below code? thanks

In actions.js

```
export const web3Loaded = (eth) => {
  const web3 = new Web3(eth);
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: WEB3_LOADED,
      connection: web3,
    });
    return web3; // it remains a promise
  };
};
```

In App.jsx

```
useEffect(() => {
    const loadBlockchain = async () => {
      if (window.ethereum) {
        try {
          await window.ethereum.enable();
          const web3 = web3Loaded(window.ethereum);
          console.log("web3", web3); // it returns a promise hence I'm unable to call the getId method
          const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
          console.log("networkId", networkId);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(
            "Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!"
          );
        }
      }
    };
    loadBlockchain();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an await when calling web3Loaded will solve the issue

```
useEffect(() => {
    const loadBlockchain = async () => {
      if (window.ethereum) {
        try {
          await window.ethereum.enable();
          const web3 = await web3Loaded(window.ethereum);
          console.log("web3", web3); // it returns a promise hence I'm unable to call the getId method
          const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
          console.log("networkId", networkId);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(
            "Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!"
          );
        }
      }
    };
    loadBlockchain();
  }, []);
```